# I want to install and configure MySQL Server silently with remote access

Tags: windows-7, mysql, database, remote-connection, nsis

How NSIS MySql Silent install and configure to enable remote machine access.

```
**ExecWait "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=root ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=MIX Port=3306 RootCurrentPassword=root" SkipNetworking=no AddBinToPath=yes**
```

It works fine for localhost, but problem with Remote IP access

Comment: What error do you get when it fails?

Comment: work fine for local machine,but when i am going to access from remote machine it shows the "'PC Name' is not allowed to connect to this mysql server"

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Comment: Is there any way to access remote machine database without FLUSH PRIVILAGE, I mean solve by the instance configure command line.

Comment: Thanx @MaQleod for working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are trying to connect the mysql  from another machine,

First you need add the remote ip in the local  mysql database where you are trying to connect from remote machine .Please execute the condition in the local machine

1) 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '[user name]'@'[remote machine name]' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]' WITH GRANT OPTION;'

Example:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'remote' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Where root is the username and remote is servername and password is password.

2) FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Once done,please try to reconnect the MySQL and you would be able to connect it.

Comment: I want this operation done by command line for all machine access as remote.

Comment: Thanx @vembutech for answer. my work is done with this solution.